# Unit testing: should I test my fake objects?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

Fake objects (and all test doubles in general) are used to assist in unit tests, but as they contain code, question arises - should they be tested?

On one hand, they are code after all so it should be tested, on the other hand, it is not production code, so testing it seems less important.

I try to write tests for fake objects, as it often doesn't take much time and can save a lot more time debugging, but those tests still look weird to me.

By fake object I mean [Gerard Meszaros definition](http://xunitpatterns.com/Fake%20Object.html):

> A Fake Object is a much simpler and lighter weight implementation of
>   the functionality provided by the DOC without the side effects we
>   choose to do without.

Comment: What is a fake object? A mock? How do you test that?

Comment: the word "fake" is overloaded. you need to specify more clearly what you mean by a fake object, and in what manner you intend to test it, what you expect to gain from it and so on.

Comment: If you cannot simply use mocks or very simple fake objects, but require very complex fake objects, then that may be a sign that there's a problem with your code. Obviously, testing could be done infinitely - you write a test, then a test to test your test, then a new test to test the test that tests your original test, etc.etc. But normally we don't do that but try to make our tests so simple that testing them is not required. Same thing with fake objects. If you actually need very complex fake objects, either you can test them or refactor your code to not require them anymore (preferable).

Comment: My fake objects are simple, but I feel simple (but not trivial) code should be tested.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the fakes are not production code you should test it because your test depends of correct execution of this fakes, if the fakes don't work right then the tests either. I think that any function thats contains some logic in a proyect should be tested, even if its not production code.

Answer (score 0):

You should test if the system satisfies the requirements. It's impossible to test exactly everything.

The idea of the fake objects is just to provide a class instance with static data so you can check what will happen with this particular value.

It's good idea to have integration tests, where you can check how the system is working with all of your classes. If there is a problem, your unit tests may be more concrete about where exactly is the problem.

If you want to test your tests after all - this presentations may give you a better idea - http://www.infoq.com/presentations/kill-better-test

Comment: "You should test if the system satisfies the requirements" - that's not point of unit tests. Requirements are tested by acceptance tests, not unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

A component can have dependency on other components, So to unit test a component you are faking the other components on which the "component under test" is dependent on, which is absolutely fine. Because unit test says to test a component in isolation, not in integration with other collaborating components.

Secondly, you should have production version of the collaborating component , which you are faking for the unit test of the current component. In that case, you should also have unit test for the production version of each collaborating component, which you have faked in this case.

So the basic rule is if you properly unit test each component independently or in isolation, then while they will integrated they should work. But if you want to test a components together that will be called integration test.